# Anybody have a fix for javascript comparisons with large numbers?

Tags: javascript, svg, comparison

I have been messing around with HTML and manipulating SVG's. As practice I have created a page that uses javascript to solve the pythagorean theorem and display the triangle in a 300h x 300w area. My problem I think is that when there is too much of a difference between variable "`a`" and variable "`b`" the comparison "`if(a>b)`" isn't working properly. So it works perfectly for `a=55` and `b=32` or even `a=5555` and `b=5000` but if I do `a=1001` and `b=55` it seems to run it as if `b` is greater than `a`.

```
<h2>Pythagorean theorem</h2>
<p>Enter Variable "a"<input id="vara" type="text"></p>
<p>Enter Variable "b"<input id="varb" type="text"></p>
<p><span id="a">a</span><sup>2</sup> + 
<span id="b">b</span><sup>2</sup> = 
<span id="c">c</span><sup>2</sup></p>

<script>
function pythagorean(){
var a=document.getElementById("vara").value;
var b=document.getElementById("varb").value;
var x=a * a + b * b;
var c=Math.sqrt(x);

if(a>b){
    ay=0
bx=b/a*300
}
else{
ay=300-(a/b*300)
bx=300
}

document.getElementById("a").innerHTML=a;
document.getElementById("b").innerHTML=b;
document.getElementById("c").innerHTML=c;
document.getElementById('trianglepoints').setAttribute("points",bx+",300 0,300 0,"+ay);
}

</script>

<svg id="triangle xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" height="300" width="300">
<polygon id="trianglepoints" points=""
style="fill:red;stroke:black;stroke-width:1;">
</svg>
<br />

<button type="button" onclick="pythagorean()">calculate</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be sure that you cast the *String* values returned by `element.value` to *Number*:

```
a = document.getElementById('vara').value;
a = +a;
-or-
a = Number(a);
```

Otherwise, when you compare `a > b` it will do a string comparison, and `'1001'` is less than `'55'` (first characters compared first).

Comment: Probably easier to just use `parseInt` or `parseFloat` when storing the values in `a` and `b`.

Comment: @ianpgall, it depends on what context `a` and `b` are being used in, and what values are acceptable. If `10em` were converted into `10` and then used as pixel values, it might not be intuitive to use `parseInt`, instead opting for a validation check with `isNaN`. In the end, it's important to choose the right tool for the job.